# Print array multiple variables

Tags: perl

Kindly advice I am unable to print value of a ,b &c

```
my @array = qw($a,$b,$c);
push(@new_array ,@array);

for my $x (@new_array)
{
DEBUG(" DEBUG : $x);
}
```

It showing me $a,$b,$c instead of there values.

Thanks,

Comment: If you had `use warnings` in your code, you would have been given a clue to the problem. If you had added `use diagnostics` you would have got a lot more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qw` operator creates a list of strings.  It quotes words, so it's "qw".

```
my @array = qw( x y z );
```

is exactly the same as

```
my @array = ( 'x', 'y', 'z' );
```

Your line:

```
my @array = qw($a,$b,$c);
```

is saying

```
my @array = ( '$a,$b,$c' );
```

What you want is to drop the `qw`.

```
my @array = ( $a, $b, $c );
```

Comment: Roger Boss .. ) You are STAR

Comment: I don't know why I am unable to accept your answer .... I mean check correct... Thanks

Comment: I think that there's a minimum amount of time that you have to wait before an answer can be accepted.